# Javascript imitate Chrome "+" button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I want to a create new tab with JavaScript not on the address about:blank. The address on my target page according to window.location.href is "chrome-extension://gibkoahgjfhphbmeiphbcnhehbfdlcgo/iframe.html".

```js
window.open("chrome-extension://gibkoahgjfhphbmeiphbcnhehbfdlcgo/iframe.html", '_blank');
```

The code above seems to open about:blank not the target page. How to fix this issue?

Comment: This extension should declare iframe.html in its [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources). Or you should open the tab from your background/popup script via chrome.tabs.create

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the web_accessible_resources field in the manifest.json file and fill in the iframe.html file path in it.

Details can be found at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources